# Store a cmdlet's result value in a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a cmdlet and store the result's **value** in a variable.

For example

```
C:\PS>Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select Priority
```

It lists priorities with a header. The first one for example:

```
Priority
--------
8
```

How can i store them in a variable? I've tried:

```
$var=Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select Priority
```

Now the variable is: `@{Priority=8}` and I wanted it to be `8`.

Question 2:

Can I store two variables with one cmdlet? I mean store it after the pipeline.

```
C:\PS>Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select Priority, ProcessID
```

I would like to avoid this:

```
$prio=Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select Priority
$pid=Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select ProcessID
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` flag of `Select-Object`

```
$var=Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select -expand Priority
```

Update to answer the other question:

Note that you can as well just access the property:

```
$var=(Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process).Priority
```

So to get multiple of these into variables:

```
$var=Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process
   $prio = $var.Priority
   $pid = $var.ProcessID
```

Comment: could you take a look at my question 2?

Comment: In PowerShell v3 you can do `(Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process).Priority` – very nice :)

Answer (score 4):

Just access the `Priority` property of the object returned from the pipeline:

```
$var = (Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process).Priority
```

(This won't work if `Get-WSManInstance` returns multiple objects.<sup>2</sup>)

For the second question: to get two properties there are several options, problably the simplest is to have have *one* variable* containing an object with two separate properties:

```
$var = (Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select -first 1 Priority, ProcessID)
```

and then use, assuming only one process:

```
$var.Priority
```

and

```
$var.ProcessID
```

If there are multiple processes `$var` will be an array which you can index, so to get the properties of the first process (using the array literal syntax `@(...)` so it is always a collection<sup>1</sup>):

```
$var = @(Get-WSManInstance -enumerate wmicimv2/win32_process | select -first 1 Priority, ProcessID)
```

and then use:

```
$var[0].Priority
$var[0].ProcessID
```

<sup>1</sup> PowerShell helpfully for the command line, but not so helpfully in scripts has some extra logic when assigning the result of a pipeline to a variable: if no objects are returned then set `$null`, if one is returned then that object is assigned, otherwise an array is assigned. Forcing an array returns an array with zero, one or more (respectively) elements.

<sup>2</sup> This changes in PowerShell V3 (at the time of writing in Release Candidate), using a member property on an array of objects will return an array of the value of those properties.