# How can I pass the output of a powershell get command to a variable and return output without @{output}

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

code as follows

```
$rgName = "my-rg"
$nameprefix = "vmtest"
##(following statement creates storage account with nameprefix followed by randomly generated string)
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile "C:\YourpathtoTemplates\Template.json" -storageNamePrefix $nameprefix -storageSKU Standard_LRS

##Here is the problem statement
$tsaname = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname | select 
StorageAccountName | Where-Object {$_.StorageAccountName -like 
"$nameprefix*"}
```

I need to pass the value of `$tsaname` into another command but instead its picking up `@{StorageAccountName=vmtest4rncl5tyt798}` which results in an error

Our current workaround is to instead pass the value by using split

```
$tsaname1 = ($tsaname -split "(?=$nameprefix)"|  Select -last 1).Trim("}")
```

which returns the desired value `vmtest4rncl5tyt798`

Is there a better way?

Used following statements to help troubleshoot

```
write-output = $tsaname
write-host $tsaname
write-host $tsaname1
```

Comment: Did you look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072911/store-a-cmdlets-result-value-in-a-variable-in-powershell

Comment: Can you tell me what the output of the following would be? (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname | Where-Object {$_.StorageAccountName -like "$nameprefix*"}).StorageAccountName

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the property StorageAccountName:

```
$tsaname = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname `
| Where-Object -Property StorageAccountName -like -Value "$nameprefix*" `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty StorageAccountName
```

This will return a `String` instead of an object with properties.

Alternatively you could also just use `$tsaname.StorageAccountName`