# Extended Attribute Unresolvable, Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, active-directory, escaping

I am trying to set up a method in which a user can tell me there username, I plug it in and it will return me their computerName.

//Get the Username

```
$username = Read-Host -prompt 'Username'
```

//Get the DistinguishedName and store it

```
$usernameDN = Get-ADUser $username -properties * | SELECT DistinguishedName
```

//Get the ComputerName
//This one fails everytime

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq $usernameDN} -properties * | SELECT CN,ManagedBy
```

//Error I receive...almost as if it has to be a string

> Get-ADComputer : Invalid value: '' specified for extended attribute:
>   'ManagedBy'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq $usernamedn} -properties * | SE ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
>   ands.GetADComputer

//So you put it as a string

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq '$usernamedn'} -properties * | SELECT CN,ManagedBy
```

//Error

> Get-ADComputer : Identity info provided in the extended attribute:
>   'ManagedBy' could not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an object with
>   identity: '$usernamedn' under: 'DC=****,DC=*****'.'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq '$usernamedn'} -properties * |  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADIdentityResolutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException
>   ,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

//However if you replace the variable with the literal DistinguishedName...it will work

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq 'CN=*******\, ***** *.,OU=********,OU=*****,OU=******,DC=*****,DC=******'} -properties * | SELECT CN,ManagedBy
```

//Result

```
CN        ManagedBy
--        ---------
********* CN=**\, ** *.,OU=***,OU=***,OU=***,DC=***,DC=**
********* CN=**\, ** *.,OU=***,OU=***,OU=***,DC=***,DC=**
```

So I'm thinking my issue is that the Filter requires it to be string, but I can't figure out the right escape to make the variable read that way.

I tried to do the string formatting as well, but I don't completely understand that yet

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `-LDAPFilter` instead of `-Filter` and using an LDAP filter string:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(managedBy=$usernameDN)"
```

It is worth your while to learn the [LDAP search filter syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475.aspx), since that's what PowerShell has to "translate" the `-Filter` into anyway.

Comment: This returns no errors, but returns an empty result as well; which i know isn't the case since I can hard code the value of the variable and it will work.

Comment: My issue was storing the variable incorrectly. I was storing the full value instead of using -expand to only catch the literal value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072911/store-a-cmdlets-result-value-in-a-variable-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

This was simply an expression problem, your example works fine for me. You are just missing the () inside the {}.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(ManagedBy -eq $usernameDN)} -properties * | SELECT CN,ManagedBy
```