# Copy the latest uploaded file from S3 bucket to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a cron job set that moves the files from an EC2 instance to S3

```
aws s3 mv --recursive localdir s3://bucket-name/ --exclude "*" --include "localdir/*"
```

After that I use `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/data1/ E:\Datafolder` in .bat file and run task scheduler in Windows to run the command.

The issue is that s3 sync command copies all the files in `/data1/` prefix.

So let's say I have the following files:

Day1: file1 is synced to local.
Day2: file1 and file2 are synced to local because file1 is removed from the local machine's folder.

I don't want them to occupy space on local machine. On Day 2, I just want file2 to be copied over.

Can this be accomplished by AWS CLI commands? or do I need to write a lambda function?

I followed the answer from [Get last modified object from S3 using AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062365/get-last-modified-object-from-s3-using-aws-cli)

but on Windows, the `|` and `awk` commands are not working as expected.

Comment: Be aware that `aws s3 sync` has a `--delete` option where files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted from the destination during the sync.

Comment: In my case, on day 1 when file1 is synced to destination, the file is moved to another folder for processing. So on day 2, the destination doesn't have any files but source have file1 and file2. I just want to sync file2 on day 2 etc.

Comment: In order to do that some local process needs to remember what was previously uploaded to S3. It can't determine that from the sync target bucket because, if I understand you correctly, the objects have already been moved from that target  bucket to another processing bucket.

Comment: The bucket is the source and the destination is folder on the windows server 2008 R2. The source bucket will have a file uploaded daily from an EC2 instance. When I use `sync` command on Windows Server on-prem, it copies over the files from S3 to dest. folder on Windows. The file1 is moved to another folder on Windows. The destination folder is now empty. On next sync, I will have file1 and file2 but I only want file2 copied to destination because it is the latest one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified answer to work with Windows `.bat` file. Uses Windows cmd.exe

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix data1/ --query "sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key" --output text') do set object=%%i
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET-NAME/%object% E:\Datafolder
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the name of the object that has the most recent Last Modified date, you can use:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

Therefore (using shell syntax), you could use:

```bash
object=`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix data1/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text`

aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET-NAME/$object E:\Datafolder
```

You might need to tweak it to get it working on Windows.

Basically, it gets the bucket listing, sorts by `LastModified`, then grabs the name of the last object in the list.

Comment: Would this work with AWS CLI v1? That's what I have it installed on Windows Server because CLI v2 is not compatible with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Yes, it should work fine.

Comment: No this didn't work on Windows. I got an error:

 C:Windows \system32\object=`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix data1/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text`

'object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You'll need to use the PowerShell equivalent to storing the result of another command. I'm not a PowerShell person, but looking at [Store a cmdlet's result value in a variable in Powershell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072911/store-a-cmdlets-result-value-in-a-variable-in-powershell) suggests you could use `$object=` at the front (with the dollar sign).